# CSS and BS4 - float left not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to align 9 cards in a 3 by 3 format, max. When viewing on a smaller device it should shrink until it's just a list of 9 cards.

**CSS:**

```
.cardContainer{
    width: calc(54rem + 60px);
    margin: auto;
}

.card{
    width: 18rem;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

I am using **Bootstrap 4**, *beta 3*. No other styles have changed.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cardContainer">

@foreach($cijfers as $cijfer)

    <div class="card">
        @if($cijfer['cijfer'] >= 8)
            <img class="card-img-top" src="check.png" alt="Card image cap">
        @else
            <img class="card-img-top" src="cross.png" alt="Card image cap">
        @endif
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{$cijfer['vak']}}: {{$cijfer['cijfer']}}</h5>
        </div>
    </div>

@endforeach

</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

I've zoomed out the page a bit so you could see the whole page.

Why is this happening and how could I fix it?

Comment: If you want to build this layout with floats all cards must have the same height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your "x" images are a tiny bit higher than the checkmark images, so the floated x goes under the checkmark in the second line because there's still some vertical space left under the checkmark, left of the second element. You can even see that if you look very close.

Make sure both element types/images have exactly the same height, this will fix your problem.